# Android web browser (ICS) does not invoke MIME-type handler

Tags: android, browser, mime-types, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have an application which is subscribed to a particular MIME-type (application/vnd.oma.dd+xml which is OMA DL descriptor - DD). It is launched when the user navigates to the DD link in the standard  Android browser.

My activity was launched successfully on GB, but the ICS browser handles this MIME-type by it own, it opens the descriptor as XML in a separate tab. No intent was sent from browser.

The question:
- Are there any changes in the way how ICS browser process MIME-types?
- Is there any workaround?

** update:
Pls use this test link: `http://220.128.71.175/DRM/DD/S-I-I-jpg.dd`
Server returns "Content-type:application/vnd.oma.dd+xml" but the ice cream sandwich (ICS) stock browser does not open the handler registered by manifest:

`<data android:mimeType="application/vnd.oma.dd+xml">`

At the same time GB browser launches the handler correctly.

Thanks in advance!

**** update 2
Seems similar issue reported to Google: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22971
The proposed solution did not help me thought...

Comment: Do you have a sample URL we could try?

Comment: When you say ICS browser, are you talking about the stock browser?  Or are you referring to the browser on your particular ICS device, which may be developed by the manufacturer?

Comment: - 2CommonsWare
I added URL into the question

- Josh
I am talking about default stock browser. Issue reproduced on Google Galaxy Nexus.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an HTC handset? It's possible that HTC's Linkify Dispatcher is getting in the way.

See here: http://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-one-s/173238-htclinkifydispatcher-what.html

And here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1696536

Comment: Thank Mike, but this observed on many handsets starting from Google Nexsus which is reference defice